# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'. Error when trying to sort a list

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a list in an ascending way with the following code:

```
def metodoburbuja( array ):
    length = (array)- 1

    for i in range(0, length):
        for j in range (0, length):
            if array [j] > array [ j + 1]:
                aux = array [j]
                array [j] = array [j + 1]
                array [j + 1] = aux
    return array 

lista_uwu = [2,3,5,4]
print(metodoburbuja(lista_uwu))
```

I am currently a beginner at arrays, but so far, from what  I read, the issue is on length = (array)- 1

It is not possible to subtract it, but I don't know the solution for it

Comment: You may intended to write `length = len(array)- 1`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that line? If you are trying to find the length, just do `len(array)`

Comment: note, this is a *list* not an array. Also note, this is not a compiler error, this is a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subtracting the array use:

`length = len(array) -1`

Comment: Thank you so much, MATOS. Such an easy solution, man. My head was burning lol. Thank you!

Comment: Hey no problem, happens to the best of us